# how to make this div not resizeable and draggable on firefox using contenteditable=true

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

this is my code:

```
<div contenteditable=true style="position:absolute;top:300px;width:200px;height:300px;background:red;color:black;">
        ddwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
</div>
```

i use `contenteditable=true` to make the div editable, but it also can resizeable and draggable on firefox ,

so how to make it not  resizeable  and draggable

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the contenteditable div inside another that has the positioning you want:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:300px;width:200px;height:300px;background:red;color:black;">
    <div contenteditable=true>
        ddwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
    </div>
</div>
```